# How to use Teamviewer 14 to perform remote debugging using Visual Studio in Window

Tags: windows, visual-studio, remote, teamviewer, visual-studio-2017

I am developing Windows C++/C# application running on Windows 7 and 10.

I am using Teamviewer 14 (Coporate license) to access to Customer's PC in other part of the world to perform troubleshooting.

Please would someone provide instruction how to perform remote debugging using Visual Studio 2017 or any earlier version ?

I understand that Teamviewer client can obtain the IP Address of the remote PC. Can I enter this IP Address in Visual Studio Remote debugger to connect up with this remote PC ? Would Firewall be an issue ?

Many thanks
Song

Comment: Have the app send verbose logs to event viewer or a log file and then look it over. Otherwise, setup a machine emulating the remote OS, etc. and then troubleshoot that machine locally or via a VM, etc. rather than trying to troubleshoot remotely via Team VIewer

Comment: Often computers don't have a public IP (NAT router in between) and if that is not the case a firewall is in between blocking incoming connections. The only chance I see to get a connections is if you connect both computers to the same server via SSH. The customers computer exposes the debugging port via reverse port forwarding to the server SSHing into. Your PC could then also do port forwarding for that port.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the [VPN](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/6354-teamviewer-vpn) in TeamViewer. After the connection is established, you can attach the debugger to a process running on the remote computer like you do on your LAN.